# Different language support in Marklogic search

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

I have requirement where I need to support multilingual support in search.

e.g. Could I pass  “repollo” (Spanish for cabbages) and it would match to cabbages

I have "cabbages" keyword in ML database.

Can any one suggest how it could be possible in search API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MarkLogic doesn't have translation features, but you could pre-parse such terms, and expand the query with translations using a custom made thesaurus or ontology.

HTH!